# LLDB "Fix-it applied" seems to be incorrect about what I wanted to print

Tags: swift, xcode, lldb

I am using Xcode 10 and Swift and I have a breakpoint in my code:

```
    let logoWPoints = logoUIImage.size.width
    let logoHPoints = logoUIImage.size.height
    let logoScale = logoUIImage.scale
    let logoWPixels = logoWPoints * logoScale
    let logoHPixels = logoHPoints * logoScale // <--- breakpoint
```

I type in the console in LLDB "print logoWPoints" which results in the error:

> (CGFloat) $R0 = 281   Fix-it applied, fixed expression was: 
>       logoWPixels

Wrong! I want logoWPoints just like I typed. I've been seeing this lately. What's the deal?

**UPDATE** - When I use the frame variable command in LLDB, I can see the message that logoWPoints isn't available:

> (CGFloat) logoWPoints = variable not available

Strangely, if I print out what that equals (logoUIImage.size.width) I get the result just fine. So why does it say it's not available?

Comment: Can't tell what the `print` command does in LLDB off the top of my head. How about `p logoWPoints`?

Comment: It's the same thing as far as I can tell, and I get the same fix-it message.

Answer (score 0):

There's already an answer to the question that leads back to the "variable not available" message in connection to the "Fix-it applied" message, which relates to a compiler optimization.

For those that are having the Fix-it problem, see this answer for details: [lldb error: variable not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040777/lldb-error-variable-not-available)

Comment: So the answer is that you were trying to debug a release build? If so, perhaps just delete the question, as it's a pure duplicate.

Comment: Someone might have trouble finding the answer if they are getting the fix-it message and have no idea why.

Comment: Yeah, good point. Unfortunately I don't think you can really post this answer as an answer to the other question, because the review queue busybodies will shut it down as a "me too" answer. So let's go the other way: how about improving your answer so that it's not a link-only, and states explicitly that your mistake was debugging an optimized build?

Comment: I will reformulate my answer